# My script not working to cycle through spans

Tags: javascript

When the page is refreshed it should cycle through all spans. It appears to only cycle through the first two 0 and 1

Javascript client script

```
  <script>
      var rand1 = Math.round(Math.random());
      $(".sp-" + rand1).removeClass("hidden");
  </script>
  </clientscript>
```

spans are as follows

````
<span class="sp-0 hidden">{CLIENTFIRST} {CLIENTLAST} {CLIENTPARTY}, {CAND4FIRST} {CAND4LAST} {CAND4PARTY}, {CAND1FIRST} {CAND1LAST} {CAND1PARTY}, {CAND2FIRST} {CAND2LAST} {CAND2PARTY}, {CAND3FIRST} {CAND3LAST} {CAND3PARTY}, or {CAND5FIRST} {CAND5LAST} {CAND5PARTY}</span>
<span class="sp-1 hidden"> {CAND3FIRST} {CAND3LAST} {CAND3PARTY}, {CAND1FIRST} {CAND1LAST} {CAND1PARTY}, {CAND2FIRST} {CAND2LAST} {CAND2PARTY}, {CLIENTFIRST} {CLIENTLAST} {CLIENTPARTY}, {CAND5FIRST} {CAND5LAST} {CAND5PARTY}, or {CAND4FIRST} {CAND4LAST} {CAND4PARTY}</span>
<span class="sp-2 hidden">{CAND2FIRST} {CAND2LAST} {CAND2PARTY},  {CAND3FIRST} {CAND3LAST} {CAND3PARTY}, {CAND4FIRST} {CAND4LAST} {CAND4PARTY}, {CAND5FIRST} {CAND5LAST} {CAND5PARTY}, {CLIENTFIRST} {CLIENTLAST} {CLIENTPARTY}, or {CAND1FIRST} {CAND1LAST} {CAND1PARTY}</span>
<span class="sp-3 hidden">{CAND1FIRST} {CAND1LAST} {CAND1PARTY}, {CAND3FIRST} {CAND3LAST} {CAND3PARTY}, {CAND5FIRST} {CAND5LAST} {CAND5PARTY}, {CAND2FIRST} {CAND2LAST} {CAND2PARTY}, {CAND4FIRST} {CAND4LAST} {CAND4PARTY}, or {CLIENTFIRST} {CLIENTLAST} {CLIENTPARTY}</span>
<span class="sp-4 hidden">{CAND4FIRST} {CAND4LAST} {CAND4PARTY}, {CAND5FIRST} {CAND5LAST} {CAND5PARTY}, {CAND1FIRST} {CAND1LAST} {CAND1PARTY}, {CLIENTFIRST} {CLIENTLAST} {CLIENTPARTY}, {CAND3FIRST} {CAND3LAST} {CAND3PARTY}, or {CAND2FIRST} {CAND2LAST} {CAND2PARTY}</span>
<span class="sp-5 hidden">{CAND5FIRST} {CAND5LAST} {CAND5PARTY}, {CLIENTFIRST} {CLIENTLAST} {CLIENTPARTY}, {CAND4FIRST} {CAND4LAST} {CAND4PARTY}, {CAND1FIRST} {CAND1LAST} {CAND1PARTY}, {CAND3FIRST} {CAND3LAST} {CAND3PARTY}, or {CAND2FIRST} {CAND2LAST} {CAND2PARTY}</span>```
````

Comment: well have you looked up what random() generates?

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random` returns values from 0 to (but not including) 1. If you want to get random values from 0 to 5 you would have to do

```
Math.round(Math.random()*5)
```